# xoxco tagging : force lowercase to avoid duplicates

Tags: javascript, plugins, tagging

Trying my hand on the **xoxco tagging plugin**.
It works great, however, it doesn't identify that the same words in different cases are duplicates, e.g. :
"**This**" and "**this**" is considered the same.

There is no hook before the tag actually gets added, where one can capture and modify the input.

Is there a way to add a hook or convert it to lower ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`caseSensitive` option added in dev branch (https://github.com/xoxco/jQuery-Tags-Input/tree/develop) but not in release version yet